# Why site wont identify itself as CLI if it was run as CLI?

Tags: php, command-line-interface

the site Im developing has only this:

```
echo php_sapi_name();
```

now from CMD, I run this:

```
php -d display_errors=1 -r "echo file_get_contents('http://site');"
```

it returns `apache2handler` instead of `cli`. Why?

Comment: You are fetching the file over `http` and Apache is serving it up.

Comment: then how to run correctly? :) sorry Im new to CMD

Comment: To get `cli` as the output of `php_sapi_name `, you have to run the file directly from php client: `php file.php`.

Comment: BTW, I'm assuming that you have access to the file through your file system, not only from Apache (http).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the following command:

```
php -d display_errors=1 -r "echo file_get_contents('http://site');"
```

You're actually loading the file from Apache (using the HTTP protocol). That's why you get `apache2handler` instead of `cli`. The PHP script is running under Apache. This is the same result you get when accessing `http://site` via some browser. In this case, your PHP client is acting as your browser.

If you need to run your script from PHP client, you have to call it this way, from command line:

```
php file.php
```

You need to have access to the file from your file system. Using the above command, I'm assuming you are in the same directory as the script is.